# Atualizacão de varios Models e um unico form CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp-3

Estou tendo problemas para atualizar mais de model no mesmo form no cakephp, ja fiz diversos modos diferentes e em todos o model principal é inserido/atualizado porem o model relacionado não.

Meu controller está assim:

```
    $this->loadModel('Jobs');

    $campanha = $this->Campanhas->newEntity();
    $jobs = $this->Jobs->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $jobs = $this->Jobs->patchEntity($jobs, $this->request->data);
        $campanha = $this->Campanhas->patchEntity($campanha, $this->request->data);
        $save = $this->Campanhas->save($campanha);
        if ($save) {   

            $jobs['campanha_id'] = $save->id;

            $savejob = $this->Job->save($jobs);
            if($savejob){
                $this->Flash->success(__('The job has been saved.'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }else{
                $this->Flash->success(__('The job hasnt been saved.'));
            }

        }else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The job hasnt been saved.'));
        }
    }
```

porem, como eu disse antes, os dados do model "Campanhas" são inseridos, porem os do model "Jobs" não.

O form está assim:
    `<fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Campanha') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('Campanhas.nome');
            echo $this->Form->input('Campanhas.data', ['class' => 'datepicker']);
            echo $this->Form->input('Campanhas.cliente_id', ['options' => $cadastros, 'id' => 'cliente_id']);
            echo $this->Form->input('Campanhas.contato_id', ['options' => $contatos, 'id' => 'contato_id']);
            echo $this->Form->input('Campanhas.requisitante_id', ['options' => $users]);
            echo $this->Form->input('Campanhas.briefing');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Job') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('Jobs.nome');
            echo $this->Form->input('Jobs.status_id', ['options' => $status]);
            echo $this->Form->input('Jobs.prioridade_id', ['options' => $prioridades]);
            echo $this->Form->input('Jobs.iniciar');
            echo $this->Form->input('Jobs.concluir');
            echo $this->Form->input('Jobs.estimado');
            echo $this->Form->input('Jobs.gasto');
            echo $this->Form->hidden('Jobs.campanha_id');
        ?>
    </fieldset>`

Ja verifiquei as variaveis `$jobs` e `$campanhas` ambas estão corretas e com os dados vindos do form, e nao apresenta nenhum erro e nem o sucesso, apenas salva a campanha e não salva o job.

Alguma luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa criar objetos diferentes quando se tem um relacionamento.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations

Cria o relacionamento nas models

```
//Model Campanhas
$this->hasOne('Jobs');

//Model Jobs
$this->belongsTo('Campanhas');
```

Especifique na criação do objecto da campanha que você vai salvar o relacionamento

```
$this->Campanhas->patchEntity($campanha, $this->request->data, [
    'associated' => ['Jobs']
]);
```

Aconselho a você sempre verifica se tem algum erro e retorna a mensagem correta para o usuário, Exemplo:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $campanha = $this->Campanhas->patchEntity($campanha, $this->request->data, [
        'associated' => ['Jobs']
    ]);

    if($errors = $campanha->errors()) {
        $this->Flash->error('Ocorreu o(s) seguinte(s) error(s):', [
            'params'=>$errors
            ]);
    }
    else if ($this->Campanhas->save($campanha)) {
        $this->Flash->success('The job has been saved.');

        $this->redirect([
            'action'=>'add',
            $campanha->id
            ]);
    }
}
```

Altere seu formulario para

```
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Campanha') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('nome');
        echo $this->Form->input('data', ['class' => 'datepicker']);
        echo $this->Form->input('cliente_id', ['options' => $cadastros, 'id' => 'cliente_id']);
        echo $this->Form->input('contato_id', ['options' => $contatos, 'id' => 'contato_id']);
        echo $this->Form->input('requisitante_id', ['options' => $users]);
        echo $this->Form->input('briefing');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Job') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('job.nome');
        echo $this->Form->input('job.status_id', ['options' => $status]);
        echo $this->Form->input('job.prioridade_id', ['options' => $prioridades]);
        echo $this->Form->input('job.iniciar');
        echo $this->Form->input('job.concluir');
        echo $this->Form->input('job.estimado');
        echo $this->Form->input('job.gasto');
        echo $this->Form->hidden('job.campanha_id');
    ?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Acredito que eu estava misturando informações de varias versões antigas e tentando fazer funcionar. Os relacionamentos estão certos e tudo mais, e rodando do jeito que voce me recomendou ele retorna `Ocorreu o(s) seguinte(s) error(s):` sem a lista de erros que ocorreu. Preciso inicializar a `$errors` de alguma forma?

Comment: Fiz umas modificações e o erro mudou, agora e retorna que o `$event` é `Undefined variable`

Comment: Fiz uma correção, muda o `$event->id` para `$campanha->id`, como eu copei de um cóido que tinha, esqueci de mudar essa variável, provavelmente mostrou os erros sem exibir a lista, pois a sua model não esta validando nada, mas não foi possível salvar

Comment: acho que é o caminho, mas agora ele cadastrou a campanha, redirecionou mas ainda nao adicionou o Job

Comment: Tenta deixar os dados que você esta enviando para form, parecido com esse formato http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasone-associations, vou editar o seu form e colocar na resposta

Comment: Realmente o problema esta no relacionamento, coloquei o Form como voce sugeriu e o relacionamento como `hasOne` e ele salvou, porem, a campanha deverá ter mais de um job. Nao sei se minha logica esta errada, mas mesmo com o hasOne futuramente esta mesma campanha podera ter mais jobs?

Comment: Cara, testei aqui e deu certo, adicionei um outro job para a mesma campanha e foi tudo OK, valeu pela sua ajuda!